# Library with identifier XXXXXXX is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a spreadsheet for tracking projects status that sends custom notifications to people watching particular project(s). I have moved 99% of code to external library and I have referenced it within spreadsheet script. One of actions that happens every minute (trigger) is to synchronize project changes between multiple sheets within that spreadsheet. It happens that less then 10 times for 1440 executions (every minute in 24 hours) I am getting an error saying that my library is missing:

**Library with identifier XXXXXXX is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)**

I am using versioning on this library and all production spreadsheets have "Development Mode" set to off.

Do you know what is happening and what should I check to stop those errors being raised and sent?

Comment: Can somebody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [release notes for November 4 2013](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#november_2013), a fix for sporadic missing library errors has been rolled out. (Refer to [Issue 2817](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2817).)

At the same time, a change was introduced such that "If a version of a library has been deleted by the library owner, scripts can no longer use that version." Previously, a script could have been using version 3 of a library, say, even after that version had been deleted. Suddenly, around November 4, that script would have begun failing. The fix in this case is to update the resources used by the script to refer to a still-existing version of the library.