# Why can't I import a Library in Google Scripts editor?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've recently created a Google Scripts new Project, called Database. Then, I've used a saved version (version 4) of that script in another project and afterwards dropped (by accident) that version of Database. Now, even if a create a new version, when I open in the menu Resources > Libraries of nthe new project, the Database project appears with the version 4.
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlvxL.png)

When I try to change it and save, the following error appears:
A biblioteca com o identificador Database está ausente. Talvez tenha sido excluída.
(The library with the identifier Database is missing. Maybe it has been excluded).

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this post: [Library with identifier XXXXXXX is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894523/library-with-identifier-xxxxxxx-is-missing-perhaps-it-was-deleted).

> According to the [release notes for November 4 2013](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#november_2013), a fix for sporadic missing library errors has been rolled out. (Refer to [Issue 2817](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2817).)
>
> At the same time, a change was introduced such that "If a version of a library has been deleted by the library owner, scripts can no longer use that version." Previously, a script could have been using version 3 of a library, say, even after that version had been deleted. Suddenly, around November 4, that script would have begun failing. The fix in this case is to update the resources used by the script to refer to a still-existing version of the library.

Also as stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125665/library-with-identifier-labelservices-is-missing-perhaps-it-was-deleted-som), it seems that there is a problem where sometimes libraries get out of sync. You may need to create new versions for the libraries even though these are in development mode.